# Когда создается база данных?

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Я немного не понимаю момент в создании базы данных, помогите.

Допустим у нас есть класс `DBHelper`, наследуемый от `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Когда идет запуск базы данных через конструктор `DBHelper(Context context)`, а в нем вызов `super(context, "myDatabase", null, 1)`, что происходит когда базы данных нет? Как я понял, запускается метод `onCreate`, a в нем команда `execSQL` (в ней указывается создаваемая таблица со столбцами), но в этой команде указывается уже **таблица в** базе данных. Это значит, что база данных была создана ранее, но когда и как? Объясните пожалуйста.

Моя догадка: она создалась при вызове в конструкторе `super`, с названием и номером версии переданным ей в аргументах, но я не уверен в этом, потому что нигде об этом не слышал.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Если писать более развернуто, выйдет другой вопрос, придется скинуть кучу кода и тд. В данный момент не стоит так делать.

Comment: [Здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)  вроде доступно написано, что конструктор создает новую базу данных, а в случае указания имени и файл на носителе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, все верно. Когда вызывается `onCreate`, сама база данных уже существует.

Об этом явно не пишут, потому что `SQLiteOpenHelper` для того и создан, чтобы не думать о процессе создания БД. Создал обьект `SQLiteOpenHelper`, база данных готова.